# How to get Javascript function return in Thymeleaf @{...} link expression

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to dynamically change form action link with javascript function which calculates and returns the action link base on some logic.

```
<form id="editForm" th:method="post" th:action="@{\''+linkProcess()+'\'}" th:object="${editObj}">
 //form content
</form>

 function linkProcess(){
 let link=//some logic to process link;
 return url;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call out to a JavaScript function in Thymeleaf, because Thymeleaf runs on the server and the JavaScript function runs in the user's browser.

Instead, set the action on the form directly in JavaScript using something like the following:

```
document.getElementById("editForm").action = url;
```